# Why am I receiving Run time error 5 Invalid procedure call or argument?

Tags: excel, vba

I receive the error when set the pivot cache. I.e at this line:-

```
Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=StartPvt, TableName:="PivotTable2")
```

I have used this macro in another workbook and I have not received this error.

```
 Sub PivTable()
'
' Insert a pivot table
'

Dim sht As Worksheet
Dim pvtCache As PivotCache
Dim pvt As PivotTable
Dim StartPvt As String
Dim SrcData As String
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim x As Long

Set ws = Worksheets("Cash Month End")

With ws
x = .Range("b999999").End(xlUp).Row

End With

 'Data Range to pivot

SrcData = "Cash Month End!(R4C1:R" & x & "C24)"

' Insert Sheet

    Sheets.Add.Name = "Cash Pivot"

  'Where the pivot must start

    StartPvt = "Cash Pivot!R3C1"

 'Create the pivot cache

 Set pvtCache = ActiveWorkbook.PivotCaches.Create(SourceType:=xlDatabase, SourceData:=SrcData)

  'Create Pivot Table from Pivot Cache

    Set pvt = pvtCache.CreatePivotTable(TableDestination:=StartPvt, TableName:="PivotTable2")

    'Add fields

    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Segment")
        .Orientation = xlPageField
        .Position = 1
    End With


    With ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").PivotFields("Region")
        .Orientation = xlRowField
        .Position = 1
    End With
    ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable2").AddDataField ActiveSheet.PivotTables( _
        "PivotTable2").PivotFields("No."), "Sum of No", xlSum
End Sub
```

Comment: You have a space in your tab name so some single quotes a probably needed (pretend it's being used in a formula in a cell) `StartPvt = "'Cash Pivot'!R3C1"
`

Comment: Se this: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_excel-msoffice_custom-mso_2010/vba-pivot-table-run-time-error-5-invalid-procedure/a5c455b5-461a-4b9e-b166-2bdec84c4196

Comment: @JNevill Thank you!